# how to use javascript to insert random number into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, z-index

I am a complete javascript novice - how do I use the following code to insert a random number into HTML as, say a z-index value for a div?

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
```

I have no idea where to place this code (i know it must be contained by script tags, however I have no clue how to get the output into the CSS code for styling a div)

Comment: Can you show us your CSS? This will help us understand what's your problem :)

Comment: The CSS could be anything, I just need javascript to create a random number so I can insert it into div style. 

For example:



<div id="home" style="z-index: 0">Hello.</div>

I need some code to use in place of 0 so the div will have a z-index value randomly assigned between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will get an element by its ID, then apply a random z-index. Note that css notation in js is camel-case.

html:

```
<div id="someElement"></div>
```

js:

```
// get an element
var el = document.getElementById("someElement");
// apply a style. 
el.style.zIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this in HTML. Where and how do i insert it?

Comment: You would put it in a `<script>` tag like this: `<script type="text/javascript">CODE HERE</script>` and you would put it just before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: @dba, I edited the answer to show the html. Place it where Markasoftware says, and it will work.

Comment: @positlabs - could this script be edited to change any style of the div? I am also looking for it to randomly assign a vertical position between, say 1-5000px.